# How to do custom order for methodq in swagger UI when writing swagger yaml spec?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I've read other questions about how to order using apisSorter and operationsSorter. 
However in my case I want to be able to define a custom order to list several POST methods in a logical workflow order.

The catch is, since I'm using swagger-codegen, I'm only writing the swagger spec in a yaml file and can't see how to define a custom order then?